# Select with Inner Join operator and IN (long results) - Optimize Query

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I do a `MySql` query that looks for results in two different tables.

**Tables**

*Contract*
*id, contract, creditor_id, client_id, event_id*

*Invoice*
*id, contract_id, invoice, due, value*

The idea is to select the contracts using some parameters in the query, such as: 
*initial delay* and *final*, *initial value* and *final*, *events*, *creditor*.

For this, I use the `INNER JOIN`, `HAVING` and `IN`.

**Details:**
*After receiving the result, I take the values ​​and loop to make an update on each query result, using the result ID.*

I built an example in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dd73cb/2) for better visualization.

The problem is, when I do this query with very long results or thousands of lines, the query is really slow.

So, I wanted to know if there is a better way to do the same query in an optimal way.

**Query:**

```
SELECT `c`.`id`,
       `c`.`contract`,
       `c`.`creditor_id`,
       `c`.`client_id`,
       `c`.`event_id`,
       `t`.`total_value`,
       `delay`
FROM `contract` `c`
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT contract_id,
          Sum(value) total_value,
          Datediff(Curdate(), due) AS delay
   FROM invoice t GROUP  BY contract_id
   HAVING delay <= 99999
   AND delay >= 1
   AND total_value >= 1
   AND total_value < 99999) t ON `t`.`contract_id` = `c`.`id`
WHERE `c`.`creditor_id` = 1
  AND `c`.`event_id` IN(4, 7, 5, 8, 13, 3, 6, 15, 2, 24, 1, 21, 20, 14, 17, 18, 16, 23, 25, 22, 9, 10, 26, 12, 19, 11)
```

Comment: Fiddle link is broken ?

Comment: also provide execution plan for your slow query , plus info on your indexes on both tables if there is any

Comment: At first look, i can say your inner SELECT statement will definitely contribute to the delay

Comment: And why do you use `delay <= 99999` I dont see any benefit on this condition as  `99999/365 = 273years`.

Comment: And while you do `GROUP BY contract_id` , which `due` you are taking ?

Comment: @IndraKumarS link Fiddle fix, i use 99999 at the end of the delay to get all the delays that exist, this value is variable.

There will never be 273 years behind in application.

Comment: @eshirvana Okay, but I need to get the contract ID to loop

Comment: The subquery is incompatible with `sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

Comment: Run `EXPLAIN` on your current query and then post the result into your question. At the moment, you can try adding index on `contract.contract_id` [like this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=9a976e775e64bfe152a028832cb72b5b)

Comment: Are you allowed to do a temporary table? If so I would approach that for the `INNER JOIN` part. Also re-writing the `>=` `<=` to `BETWEEN` for better readability.

Answer (score 0):

- If "1..99999" means "any value", then remove the test from the query.  That is construct a different query when the user wants an open-ended test.
- Deal with the lack of `due` in the `GROUP BY`.
- Change `Datediff(Curdate(), due) > 123` to `due < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 123 DAY`.  That will give us a chance to use `due` in an `INDEX`.
- Qualify `due` and `value`; we can't tell which table they are in.
- Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.
- `c` could use `INDEX(creditor_id, event_id)`, but after the above issues are addressed, there may be an even better index.

Comment: I need to use `1 ... 99999`, because this way I look for all contracts that are late, in the same way that it can be `1 to 365`, to look for all contracts with a delay of 1 year.
I can have contracts 1.2...20 years late ​​and I need to be able to filter these.